# Flutter SingleChildScrollView in drawer does not shift upward when keyboard opened

Tags: flutter

How can I force shifting widgets into drawer upward when the keyboard opened?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9AKY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `focusNode` of a textflield to catch the `onFocus` event and force scroll on your SingleChildScrollView with a `ScrollController`